# soundManager: Preloading Multiple Sounds

Tags: javascript, audio

I have been at this for weeks, still cannot preload all of my sounds. I've resorted to a recursive function which, in theory, will not create the next sound object until the first one has loaded. Only 18 of my 31 sounds appear to be loading. If I add an alert to the onload handler, it reports a very strange result, such as:
"spic loaded"
over and over, 18 times, rather than reporting the id of each new sound. Here's the code for my two relevent modules. Have any of you come up with a reliable method of preloading multiple sounds? Thanks :-)

Earcons module:
     var Earcons = (function() {
     // Earcons are like icons, but use symbolic sounds instead of pictures
       var trackUrls = [
       "audio/newpage.mp3", "audio/fgrow.mp3", "audio/fshrink.mp3",
       "audio/slideright.mp3", "audio/slideleft.mp3", "audio/sdiv.mp3", "audio/tell.mp3",
       "audio/office_lobby.mp3", "audio/footstep.mp3", "audio/apple.mp3",
       "audio/typewriter.mp3",
       "audio/walking.mp3", "audio/macspeak.mp3", "audio/picklock1.mp3",
       "audio/gossip.mp3", "audio/winenter.mp3", "audio/winleave.mp3", "audio/beep.mp3"];

```
   var trackTitles = [
   "soundOnLoad", "soundOnGrow", "soundOnShrink", "soundOnSlideRight",
 "soundOnSlideLeft", "soundOnDiv", "soundOnParagraph", "work",
 "soundOnList", "apple", "stype", "walk", "macbook",
 "soundOnLink", "soundOnInput", "winenter", "winleave", "soundOnImage"];

   var trackPtr = 0;

   var getTrackNumber = function (trackName) {
   for (i = 0; i < trackTitles.length; i++) {
     if (trackName == trackTitles[i]) return i;
   }
   return -1;
   };

   var preload = function() {
   if (trackPtr >= trackUrls.length)
     { trackPtr = 0; return; }
   else trackPtr++;
   var soundTrack = soundManager.createSound ({id: "st" + trackPtr + "",
   url: trackUrls[trackPtr],
   autoLoad: true, autoPlay: false,
   onload: function() { preload(); } });
 };

   var unload = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < trackUrls.length; i++) {
     var soundTrack = soundManager.getSoundById ("st" + i);
     soundTrack.unload();
     soundTrack.destruct();
   }
 };

   interface = {
     trackUrls: trackUrls,
     trackTitles: trackTitles,
    getTrackNumber: getTrackNumber,
     preload: preload,
     unload: unload
   };

   return interface;
 } )();

Voice narrations module:
 var Narrations = (function() {
   var trackUrls = [
   "audio/about.mp3", "audio/webtech.mp3", "audio/screenreader.mp3",
   "audio/services.mp3", "audio/stories.mp3", "audio/settings.mp3",
   "audio/feedback.mp3", "audio/display.mp3", "audio/soundset.mp3",
   "audio/voiceset.mp3", "audio/divmain.mp3", "audio/divcenter.mp3",
   "audio/divnav.mp3"];

   var trackTitles = [
 "About This Web App", "Web Development Technologies", "What's A Screen Reader",
 "Services I Can Offer", "Stories, Poetry, Anecdotes", "Settings",
 "Send Me Your Comments", "Display Settings", "Sound Settings",
 "Voice Quality Settings", "div mainContent", "div center", "div navBar"];

 var trackPtr = 0;

 var getTrackNumber = function (trackName) {
   for (i = 0; i < trackTitles.length; i++) {
     if (trackTitles[i] == trackName) return i;
   }
   return -1;
 };

 var preload = function() {
   if (trackPtr >= trackUrls.length)
   { trackPtr = 0; return; }
   else trackPtr++;
   var voiceTrack = soundManager.createSound ({id: "vt" + trackPtr + "",
   url: trackUrls[trackPtr],
   autoLoad: true, autoPlay: false,
   onload: function() { preload(); } });
 };

 var unload = function() {
   for (i = 0; i < trackUrls.length; i++) {
     var voiceTrack = soundManager.getSoundById ("vt" + i);
     voiceTrack.unload();
     voiceTrack.destruct();
   }
 };


 interface = {
   trackUrls: trackUrls,
   trackTitles: trackTitles,
   getTrackNumber: getTrackNumber,
   preload: preload,
   unload: unload
 };

   return interface;
 } )();
```